# How can I re-define an existing mixin whilst retaining the original output?

Tags: sass, mixins

Let's say I have the following mixin:

```
@mixin foo {
    color: red;
}
```

This mixin is imported in a library, so I don't want to touch the source code. I do however want to extend the functionality of the mixin, and add my own styles to it.

So I need a way to create a new mixin with the same name, whilst retaining the original output but allowing me to add new output, something like:

```
@mixin foo {
    color: blue;
}

@mixin foo {
    @include foo; // this is the original
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Of course the above will not do what I want, but is there something I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around and came up with this which seems to work:

```
@mixin foo() {
    color: red;
}

%foo {
    @include foo;
}

@mixin foo() {
    @extend %foo;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.foo {
    @include foo;
}
```

Comment: Very clever solution. In general I'd suggest to create a new mixin instead, but I can also think of some situations where it'd be necessary to overwrite (with good documentation to not confuse future devs).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend/change code block of a Mixin using `@content;` while you have  lines inside it by default.

```
@mixin foo(){
  background:green;
  border:solid 5px black;
  @content;
}
div{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  &.one{
    +foo(){
      border:0;
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/hhb09b61/